# How to use Box Python SDK for retrieving acess token

Tags: cloud, saas

I have clientid,client secret keys obtained by creating box developer account, how do i authorize and get an access token to download a file from box account?

This i wanted to do it in my python code? I am referring to their python sdk below. It does not give specific examples as such, it mentions to redirect to a url and fetch authorization code? How do i do it in my code with out opening up the browser?

https://github.com/sookasa/box.py

In simple, how do i use clientid and client secret key to obtain access token to further use their file download apis?

Thanks in Advance!
Santhosh